# Overwriting an imported package with a folder with the same name

Tags: python

I have a python script that looks as following:

```
import sys
import package_name

if condition:
    sys.path.insert(0,subdir)
```

where subdir contains another folder with a number of python files that are slightly different from the ones located in the imported imported version.

When I later try to use the package, I am always redirected to the imported version of the package:

```
package_name.function()
```

However, when I remove the `import package_name` line, the script starts using the function found in the python file from the directory. I assumed that inserting it into the first position of path would be enough to overwrite the import, is there a way to get this setup to work without losing the import line?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want the import the package after you have modified the path?

Comment: You can just import the package as something, like `import package_name as pn`.

Comment: @IainShelvington I want to import the package and use the imported version if the condition fails, and if it doesn't I want to use the version from the inserted path

Comment: from path.package_name import function

Comment: Just put the path manipulation before the import? if the condition fails then the path won't be modified and the normal version will be imported, otherwise the version from the path will be used

Comment: @AndrewWei The problem is that I want to access it with the same code, so I can't just address it with a different name

Comment: from path import package_name as pn